# How convert audio stereo to mono in python

Tags: python, audio, mono, helper, stereotype

I have no idea how to do this. I need to turn stereo audio into mono.

Can someone help me?

I'm using pygame to play the song

```py
from pygame import mixer  
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('meh.wav')
mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: mono ? ...or stereo >   mono_left  and mono_right?

Comment: yes, exactly this ...

Comment: and if necessary to use python ? ...because you can use just sox like this : https://www.nesono.com/node/275

Comment: yeah, this is for a college job

Comment: What happens if you initialize the mixer module using `mixer.init(channels=1)`?

Comment: @Davidfranca9 Did any of the suggestions work for you?

Answer (score 3):

In general, you would simply load the audio into an array of shape `(n, k)`, where `n` is number of channels and `k` number of loaded samples. By averaging along channel axis (sum and divide by number of channels), you'd get your mono signal.

In `pygame` there are at least two ways:

- As @CodeSurgeon pointed out, do `mixer.init(channels=1)` -> [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init).
- Use [mixer.set_num_channels](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.set_num_channels) property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python interface of praat , parselmouth which guives a good estimation of Mono audio from stereo audio .

```
import parselmouth
from parselmouth import call
monoSound = call(sound,'convert To mono')
```